# Void that returns result from yes_no dialog box?

Tags: c#, dialog, return-value

I want to call a method that opens and displays a dialog window asking a question and then returning the answer. This is my attempt at that, but so far it fails.

Observe code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class mainClass {
    static public void Asker() {
        var uInput = MessageBox.Show(
            "Do you like people?",
            "Sir Askscelot",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question
        );
        return uInput;
    }

    static void Main() {
        var result = Asker();
        if (result == DialogResult.No) {
            Console.WriteLine("Why?!");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Good thing!");
        }
    }
}
```

Observe error:

[image]

Note: I am kind of new to C# so I don't know if there are more things wrong with my code other than this error I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `Asker` is listed as `void` in your code, which means that method returns no result.  However you are returning a `DialogResult` from it - which is an error.  A method cannot return a value and not return a value.

Your `Asker` method needs to be declared as:

```
static public DialogResult Asker() {
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It works now.

I do wonder though... what if I don't know what the method is going to return? What if it could return multiple things? Not really related to this question, as I have no need for this knowledge at this moment. I am just curious ;)

Comment: A method can only return one value.  It could return an `object` which is the base class of all types so it can store anything.  Usually you will know what type a method is going to return.

Comment: Usually indeed. +1 Thanks.